# Finding JAVA HOME

Tags: java, macos, java-8

So I've spent a while trying to wrap my head around whats happening. I am running OSX 10.10.5.

I need to find the Java folder so that I can set JAVA_HOME. I've installed JDK 1.8.0_73, and I know it exists. From other stackOverflow posts, I used

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

in terminal to find it and I got

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
```

However, when I go to my library folder, I don't see a Java folder at all. I tried to access it through terminal but it just says directory not found. Same if I just copy/paste the location into the PATH environments.

So where is my JDK installed if the place it is installed in doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you try `find / -name 'jdk*'`?

Comment: Are you going to `/Library` or `~/Library`?

Comment: What does `find / -name 'javac*'` show you?

Comment: In most cases when you install the jre/jdk it's installed in a central location (so you can have multiple instances installed), a symbolic link is then used to point to which ever instance you want to use, which is stored in a known location. Unfortunately I don't recall the exact locations off the top of my head

Comment: Oh Durr. I was using ~/Library and not /Library. I didn't realize which one it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `/usr/libexec/java_home` returns `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home`, then it should be at that path.

You can view its contents with

```
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I assume you used Finder to open the Library window or maybe your terminal was at `~/` and you were doing `cd Library/Java`, which may not exist.